# plotting PCA output in scatter plot whilst colouring according to to label python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I have just completed a PCA analysis of 14 variables which I have chosen to condense into 2 components.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(z)
a = pca.fit_transform(z)
```

The output this gives is in form:

```
[[ -3.84514275e+00  -1.19829226e-01]
 [ -4.78476227e+00  -1.35986090e-01]
 [ -2.26702900e+00  -1.19665853e+00]
 [ -5.01021616e+00   2.76005130e+00]
 [ -5.57580326e+00  -2.00656680e+00]
 [ -5.08184415e+00  -3.68721491e+00]
 [ -3.41505366e+00  -7.61184868e-01]
 [ -4.92439159e+00  -1.82147509e+00]
...
 [ -3.34931300e+00   7.57884906e-01]]
```

I want to do the following:

1. plot each observation on a scattergraph with PC1 (x) being the first value in each array and PC2 (y) being the 2nd value.
2. colour each observation according to the corresponding label type (i.e. A=red, B=blue, C=green, etc) from the initial pre-PCA data.
3. label SELECTED (not ALL) observations with the name of the observation from the initial pre-PCA data (i.e. John, Peter, Sally, etc.)

any help is greatly appreciated for any/all of these problems.

Worth noting I attempted to do the scatter by:

```
plt.scatter(a[1], a[2])
plt.show()
```

but obviously this doesn't work as my output of a is not seperated by commas and would only plot 2 points. Can't help my head around it so would appreciate SO's input.

EDIT:

dataset in form:

```
John, A, var1, var2, var3, ..., var14
Peter, A, var1, var2, var3, ..., var14
Sally, B, var1, var2, var3, ..., var14
Cath, C, var1, var2, var3, ..., var14
Jim, A, var1, var2, var3, ..., var14
```

I'm after something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Show us a representative dataset, with labels

Comment: Your array is two-dimensional, so you need to index it with two indices. `a[:,0]` for the first column, `a[:,1]` for the second. Apart it's really unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Thanks Ernest, that solves problem 1. any ideas on 2 & 3?

Comment: Did you google "how to color a matplotlib scatter plot" or "how to annotate a matplotlib plot"?

Comment: yes, but this isnt as simple as referencing a colour since i need to look at the previously untransformed dataset to apply said colours.

Comment: i.e. if obs 1 has variable letter = B in df1 then set obs 1 from df2 as Blue

Comment: The problem is that we do not have that kind of information. That's why questions that do not contain all necessary information to answer them, usually in form of a [mcve], should be closed on SO.

Comment: you can see from my edited post what im trying to do though right? so as obvservation 1 in my example dataset has a label B I want to set observation 1 in the PCA data as a blue point

Answer (score 7):

I think your question is now very clear - thanks for editing!

Here's how the plot you describe can be created.

---

First, let's generate some example data:

```
# Params
n_samples  = 100
m_features =  14
selected_names = ['name_13', 'name_23', 'name_42', 'name_66']

# Generate
np.random.seed(42)
names    = ['name_%i' % i for i in range(n_samples)]
labels   = [np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D']) for i in range(n_samples)]
features = np.random.random((n_samples,m_features))
```

Next we do the PCA:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
features_pca = pca.fit_transform(features)
```

Then we prepare a list/array of length `n` that translates the labels `A,B,C,...` into colors. These can either be hand-selected colors...

```
# Label to color dict (manual)
label_color_dict = {'A':'red','B':'green','C':'blue','D':'magenta'}

# Color vector creation
cvec = [label_color_dict[label] for label in labels]
```

...or just a range of integers.

```
# Label to color dict (automatic)
label_color_dict = {label:idx for idx,label in enumerate(np.unique(labels))}

# Color vector creation
cvec = [label_color_dict[label] for label in labels]
```

Finally, it's time to plot.

```
# Create the scatter plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.scatter(features_pca[:,0], features_pca[:,1],
            c=cvec, edgecolor='', alpha=0.5)

# Add the labels
for name in selected_names:

    # Get the index of the name
    i = names.index(name)

    # Add the text label
    labelpad = 0.01   # Adjust this based on your dataset
    plt.text(features_pca[i,0]+labelpad, features_pca[i,1]+labelpad, name, fontsize=9)

    # Mark the labeled observations with a star marker
    plt.scatter(features_pca[i,0], features_pca[i,1],
                c=cvec[i], vmin=min(cvec), vmax=max(cvec),
                edgecolor='', marker='*', s=100)

# Add the axis labels
plt.xlabel('PC 1 (%.2f%%)' % (pca.explained_variance_ratio_[0]*100))
plt.ylabel('PC 2 (%.2f%%)' % (pca.explained_variance_ratio_[1]*100)) 

# Done
plt.show()
```

As you can see, the different colors can be fed into `plt.scatter` via the `c` kwarg. In addition, I recommend `edgecolor=''` as this often looks more clear. You can play with `alpha` to increase/decrease transparency, which will make the labeled points stand out more/less.

The labels are simply placed on the plot using `plt.text` with the appropriate x and y positions, which I here adjust a little bit (using `labelpad`) so that the labels are nicely positioned next to the marker.

For the star marker, note that `vmin` and `vmax` are important if you are using a numeric color vector, since otherwise the stars will end up in the wrong color.

Here's the result (using the manually defined colors):

[image]